# C# finding OS and calling reference based on OS

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to call a script from C# to run in powershell, now this works perfectly fine on my machine which is Windows 10 64 bit, however on Windows 7 machines the powershell references are located in a different place and I'm assuming this is why I am getting an exception when hitting the button to run the script, `System.IO.FileNotFound`-exception.

So back to my original question after some context, can I check the OS and dependant on the result call a different Reference.

If im not making sense please let me know and I'll be happy to discuss further!

Comment: google c# find OS version?

Comment: and then pulling the different reference? read my whole question before jumping on my back thanks (y)

Comment: that was not your main question. your main question is how to find OS. you said it in a way that its like you know where are the references... you should change your question. btw i think it can be done with help of windows register...

Comment: right well that makes more sense! :) i said if im not making sense to ask, how would i do that sorry?

Comment: You could try referencing the PowerShell assemblies without specifying their version and seeing if the script executes successfully on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a page on MSDN describing how to get the OS version.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx). What you can do is find the version and set up conditions based on what version you get: if it's Win10, go to `C:\Windows\Directory\`, if it's Win7 then go to `C:\Windows\DifferentDirectory\`. As long as you know where the files you need are, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled your application against a newer PowerShell-version than your Windows 7 client has installed. The exception should say which version it's looking for. A Windows 7 client has PowerShell 2.0 unless you've updated WMF.

You have two options:

- Compile you application against System.Management.Automation 6.1.7601 (PowerShell 2.0). Ex. use this NuGet-package: [System.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation)
- Update Windows Management Framework on the Windows 7 clients. The latest version is 5.0 which is the version that comes with Windows 10).